# Which tax year for healthcare bill if incurred and paid in different years

Tags: taxes, tax-deduction, healthcare, medical-bill

If I get healthcare bills in 2018 but pay them in 2019 to which year’s tax returns do they belong?

Comment: Please specify the country when asking tax questions.

Answer (score 0):

The deduction for qualified  medical bills is allowed in the tax year that you pay them, assuming that you have sufficient deductions to itemize.  If you take the standard deduction, you won’t be able to deduct them.